# Compactness of an integral operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, arzela-ascoli

I want to prove that

> The operator (linear and bounded) $T: L^2(0,1) \rightarrow L^2(0,1)$, defined by: $Tu(x)=\int_0^1\sin(x^2+y^2)u(y)dy$, is compact.

Just by using theory, it's an *Hilbert Schmidt* operator, so it's compact. Indeed, the kernel $k(x,y) = \sin(x^2+y^2) \in L^2([0,1] \times [0,1])$.

I want to use a more direct approach, by using Ascoli-Arzelà.

First of all, I see that

$|Tu(s)-Tu(t)|=| \int_0^1 [\sin(s^2+y^2)-\sin(t^2+y^2)]u(y)dy| < \varepsilon ||u||_{L^2}^2$, since $s \mapsto \sin(s^2+y^2)$ is continuous on a compact set, then it's *unformly continuous*.

Then $Tu(x)$ is continuous, and then $T: L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow C^{0}[0,1] \subset L^2([0,1])$

To prove compactness, I take $B \subset L^2(0,1)$, with $||u|| \leq M_b$, for $u \in B$. I want to prove that $T(B)$ is relatively compact in $C^0([0,1])$ by using Ascoli-Arzelà.

1. $T(B)$ is equibounded
   $|Tu(x)|=|\int_0^1 \sin(x^2+y^2) u(y) dy| \leq 1\cdot ||u||_{L^2}^2 \leq M_b$
2. Now I show equicontinuity

Again, I compute

$|Tu(s)-Tu(t)| = \int_0^1 [\sin(s^2+y^2)-\sin(t^2+y^2)]u(y)dy| \leq |s-t| ||u||_{L^2}^2$

by MVT applied to $s \mapsto \sin(s^2+y^2)$ for $s \in [0,1]$.

So $T(B)$ is equilipschitz, thus equicontinuos.

Then, by Ascoli-Arzelà, $T(B)$ is relatively compact in $C^0([0,1])$. Now, since the immersion $C^0 \hookrightarrow L^2[0,1]$ is continuos, then $T(B)$ is relatively compact in $L^2[0,1]$.

Is my second approach okay? Or do I need to fix something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is correct.  But there is an easier way. Observe that 
$$
Tu(x)=a\sin(x^2)+b\cos(x^2)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants depending on $u$. Thus, the range of $T$ is finite-dimensional and $T$ is compact.

Comment: Since $a,b$ are depending on $u$, how can I be sure that the are bounded also when $u$ blows up?

Comment: @VoB you can easily verify that $a$ and $b$ are finite...just try to figure out what they are.

Comment: Maybe you want to remark that one gets this observation using $$ \sin(x^2+y^2) = \cos(x^2)\sin(y^2) + \sin(x^2) \cos(y^2) $$

Comment: Now I figured it out: $a=\int_0^1 \cos(y^2) u(y) dy$, while $b=\int_0^1 \sin(y^2)u(y)dy$. 
Since $u \in L^2$ by assumption, then $|a| \leq ||u||_{L^2}^2 < +\infty$. Same argument holds for $b$, thus it's a finite-rank operator, thus compact.

Thanks!

Comment: @VoB So to show the boundness it's enough to say that $$|Tu(x)|=|\int_0^1 \sin(x^2+y^2) u(y) dy| \leq 1\cdot ||u||_{L^2}^2<+\infty$$ since $u\in L^2$? I mean, is it the same to bound the $L^2$ norm of $Tu(x)$ or the modulus of $Tu(x)$ to show the boundness of the operator $T$?

Comment: To show boundedness of the operator $T$ I need to prove that $||(Tu)(x)||_{L^2} \leq C ||u||_{L^2}$, for some $C >0$. I have to compute a double integral, (in dy dx)

Comment: This come from the fact that $T:L^2(0,1) \rightarrow L^2(0,1)$. If you do in your way, you're assuming that $T:L^2(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is not the case. In the boundedness inequality, for $T:X \rightarrow Y$, you always have to prove $||Tu||_{Y} \leq C ||u||_{X}$, so it depends on the norm you have on $X$ and $Y$.